# Internet Explorer Jumpy Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

I have this code to keep a heading element at the top of another element that scrolls.

It works perfectly in Firefox and Google Chrome however in IE it's excruciatingly jumpy. The code itself is very simple and I can't think how to potentially improve it.

In Chrome and Firefox the heading sits at the top permanently still all the time, however in IE it jumps around like a small child that got hold of the bag of sugar.

I can't change the HTML layout because of the `JQueryUI` `sortable` functionality I'm using

Anyway, here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/0va4dn0q/8/

```js
$('.container').scroll( function() {
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        Header = $(this).find('.header');
    Header.css('margin-top', fromTop + 'px');
});

$('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
});
```

```css
div {
   width:300px; 
}
.sortable {
    float:left;
    margin:3px solid red;
    min-height:200px;
}
.container {
    height:200px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:relative;
    cursor:move;
}
.header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:orange;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
}
.main {
    padding-top:20px;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    height:1000px;
}
.ui-state-highlight {
    height:200px;   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="main">hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="main">bye<br/>bye<br/>bye<br/></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="main">splurge<br/>splurge<br/>splurge<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="main">lorem ipsum<br/>dolor<br/>sit<br/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we change the HTML structure INSIDE the sortable container?  I really want to get the scrollbar inside the .main div, so it is next to the area that actually scrolls.

To do this, I created a new main-window class, gave it a height of 180px (200 - 20 for the header), moved the overflow from container, and removed the 20px padding from main, and it seemed to work:

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
    handle: '.header',
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
});
```

```css
div {
   width:300px; 
}
.sortable {
    float:left;
    margin:3px solid red;
    min-height:200px;
}
.container {
    height:200px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.main-window {
    height:180px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.header {
    cursor:move;
    background-color:orange;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
}
.main {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    height:1000px;
}
.ui-state-highlight {
    height:200px;   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="main-window">
            <div class="main">hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="main-window">
            <div class="main">bye<br/>bye<br/>bye<br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="main-window">
            <div class="main">splurge<br/>splurge<br/>splurge<br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="main-window">
            <div class="main">lorem ipsum<br/>dolor<br/>sit<br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, besides the fact that the scrollbars are now below the headers and the headers now extend all the way to the next one, should work.  You may or may not have some styling cleanup to do, but the scrollbars now act like you want them to without JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for giving a great answer based upon all the information I provided. Annoyingly there is but another quirk (/me cries a little). The headers aren't always used as the handle as they can be a UI element (jQueryUI Slider) instead of a textual element. Unfortunately if you take the handler off and then try and drag the scroll bar down you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/yod3s5vm/5/

Comment: Good.  If the idea works, then post it as the answer for future readers.  If you get stuck, let me know and I'll take a further look.

Comment: I basically did what you suggested but made main-window the handle element instead of container. Took over a day to configure it because of all the other things hinging on it (that I left out of my question otherwise it would be miles long). I'll award the bounty when I can (can't seem to do it from android app)

Comment: That will work.  Thanks for the explanation.  It seems enough to let the users know what you did, and besides, which container to make the handle is more about working with sortable than working with scrollbars, so if someone else is trying to do both, they can search on sortable handle and probably find the answer already.  No need to go further.  Also, I definitely learned something, so I'm glad I took the time to answer.

Answer (score 4):

The header should be outside of the container, while the container should have a margin-top of 20px, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oded/dmdfn99L/1/)

```
 <div id="header">Header</div>
 <div id="container">
    <div id="main"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Liam I can't change the HTML due to the jQueryUI `sortable` function. See the updated example code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `position: fixed` and don't set the `top` property so that it's fixed relatively.

like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/0va4dn0q/42/